# Android zoomcontrols for webview is not working. Fragment inflated per view pager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, fragment, pinchzoom

My application has an activity which loads a page viewer. Each page view is inflating a new fragment. Inside each fragment is a webview.

I've been following everything on Stack and google trying to resolve this.

Inside my onCreateView I'm using this code:

```
    WebSettings wb = mWebview.getSettings();
    wb.setSupportZoom(true);
    wb.getBuiltInZoomControls();
    wb.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    wb.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new mWebChromeClient());
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
    mWebview.loadUrl(url);
```

None of this works however, when I remove it and simply use this
        mWebview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
setDefaultzoom does infact zoomout, but not pinch and zoom.

My xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Overall everything is nice, except I hate not being able to pinch and zoom.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?  If it's Kit Kat (19) then you could be running in to issues because `setDefaultZoom()` is deprecated.  [See this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I set the SDK down to 18 to test if it would help.  mWebview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR); is still working, but the pinch and zoom is not.

Comment: Sadly, Currently what I'm doing is adding buttons to my actionbar to allow for zoomin and out by setting .Far .Medium .Close.  I don't like this idea but I've been working on this for about 6 hours.

Comment: My dirty workaround is ugly. I've set the actionbar to have zoom controls and then have the click listener for mWebView.

    wb.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
                mWebview.reload();

This is extremely ugly. Still have no clue why I can't zoom in on my webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! Thank you everyone!

Blogger.com  *(And I guess the other sites as well)* have the viewport disabled for users. 

In blogger there is HTML code preventing my site from zooming.

b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0'     name='viewport'/>  

**By changing maximum-scale=1.0 to maximum-scale=2.0** I was to finally see zoomcontrols. 

*Also, here is my code for the zoomControls*

```
    this.mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new mWebChromeClient());
    this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
    this.mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call setBuiltInZoomControls()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
// Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gaunt, this is working but I've figured it out a bit more. I'm loading a webview from blogger.com, google.com, yahoo.com also tried thechive.com for testing. All of these views the zoomcontrols do not work.   Finally I've tested a random url from a site named instant.ly, **this site allow the zoomcontrols to work.**    

Any Idea why or how I can make it work on the other sites?